# Report with details like count of each consumer in each document in each hour

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

Thank you all for taking out your time and giving suggestions. Now I have reached where I need to get report which would count of each consumer of each document in each hour.

I have come up with this logic
first get the hour, document, consumer in awk array then for each hour get the document and for that document get consumer and count of same consumer then avg_rtime.

This is my input log file.

```
document| consumer| hour| rtime|    
cust_CreateDocument OLS 23 670
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 14 685
cust_CreateDocument OLS 17 767
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 15 1186
cust_DumpDocumentProperties OLS 15 928
cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI  0 462
cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI 0 1338
cust_GetDocument LDS 11 413
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS  0 1527  
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS  0  473
```

Required output in below format.

```
Hour | document| consumer |count| avg_of_rtime|  
0 cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 2 1000=(1525+473)/2#How to compute avg_rtime   
0 cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI 2  900=(462+1338)/2   
14 cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 1 685=(685/1)
```

Comment: You should really try and give a shot at solving it. You had the logic all figured out. If you never try, you'll never learn.

Comment: I really apreciate your suggestions. I did write a very lengthy in bash and wanted to know in awk, as recenlty with help of your answers I learned a lot. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '
NR>1 {
    a[$3" "$1" "$2]+=$4
    b[$3" "$1" "$2]++
}
END {
    print "Hour | document| consumer |count| avg_of_rtime";
    for (x in a) {
        print x,b[x], a[x]/b[x] | "sort -nk1"
    }
}' input.log
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat input.log 
document| consumer| hour| rtime|    
cust_CreateDocument OLS 23 670
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 14 685
cust_CreateDocument OLS 17 767
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 15 1186
cust_DumpDocumentProperties OLS 15 928
cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI  0 462
cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI 0 1338
cust_GetDocument LDS 11 413
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS  0 1527  
cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS  0  473

$ awk '
    NR>1 {
        a[$3" "$1" "$2]+=$4
        b[$3" "$1" "$2]++
    }
    END {
        print "Hour | document| consumer |count| avg_of_rtime";
        for (x in a) {
            print x,b[x], a[x]/b[x] | "sort -nk1"
        }
    }' input.log
Hour | document| consumer |count| avg_of_rtime
0 cust_GetDocumentContentStream CPI 2 900
0 cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 2 1000
11 cust_GetDocument LDS 1 413
14 cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 1 685
15 cust_DumpDocumentProperties OLS 1 928
15 cust_GetDocumentContentStream LDS 1 1186
17 cust_CreateDocument OLS 1 767
23 cust_CreateDocument OLS 1 670
```

Comment: Thanks JS, Can you put a comment on first 3 lines what they exactly do

Comment: @random_thoughts For `array a`, we create an index of Hour, Document and Customer and add r_time to it as value. For `array b` we just calculate the occurrences of that Document and Customer for that hour is seen. Second array helps calculate the average.

Comment: Excellent logic to do it fewer lines.